# SQL Server Select query multiple results

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012, group-by

I am using SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU2) (KB3137746)

I have a table `POLICY` and trying to select rows matching with `policyNumber`. This column is of type `VARCHAR`.

First case:

```
select * 
from POLICY 
where PolicyNumber = 1234
```

It returns two rows

```
PolicyNumber  CustomerId
------------------------
001234        000789
1234          000567
```

Next, I am trying to find those cases in tables - how many such cases are there?

Second case:

```
Select Count(1) As Number_Of_policy, PolicyNumber     
From POLICY 
Group By PolicyNumber    
Having Count(1) > 1
```

It is not returning the intended rows.

Then I modified the query

Third case:

```
Select Count(1) As Number_Of_policy, CAST(PolicyNumber AS int) policyNum   
From POLICY
Group By CAST(PolicyNumber AS int)    
Having Count(1) > 1
```

It is returning rows.

My question is why this behaviour while writing normal select query? Is it by default type case and returned rows in the first case?

Answer (score 2):

The text `001234` is not the same thing as the text `1234`.  But if you cast both to integers, then they become the same number `1234`.

The moral of the story here is that if you intend the policy numbers to behave just as that, namely numbers, then store them in a numeric column.

If you are wondering why your first query returns two rows:

```
SELECT * from POLICY WHERE PolicyNumber = 1234;
```

In this case, SQL Server is doing an implicit conversion on `PolicyNumber` to integer.

Comment: That is true, but in first case, why it is returing two values? In argument if we say, we should query select * from POLICY where PolicyNumber = '1234' rather select * from POLICY where PolicyNumber = 1234; then also, for select * from POLICY where PolicyNumber = 1234 it is returning a row , which is 001234. Do not understand why?

Comment: @SaptarsiMondal in above case the `PolicyNumber` treated as varchar which is not equal  to 001234 if you have stored `PolicyNumber ` as varchar

Comment: @SaptarsiMondal as it will return only `1234` if you have `select * from POLICY where PolicyNumber = '1234'`

Comment: @SaptarsiMondal In the case of `where PolicyNumber = '1234'` you are referring to a specific string.  But in the case of `where PolicyNumber = 1234` the entire _column_ is being cast to a number, and then compared.  In this case, both `'001234'` and `'1234'` become the _number_ `1234` and are identical.